# Remove description from <title> on Home

Tags: filters, title

My theme has support for title-tag `add_theme_support('title-tag')`, but I can't remove the wordpress description `bloginfo('description')` from `<title>` on Home page.

I'm trying using this filter with no success:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', function ( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() )
        $title = "$title";

    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', function ( $title ) {
    if(is_front_page()){
        $title = get_bloginfo();
    }
    return $title;
});
```

Answer (score 9):

[`wp_get_document_title()`](https://wpseek.com/function/wp_get_document_title/) has some interesting filters - [`pre_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/) and [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/).

```
/**
 * Filter the parts of the document title.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param array $title {
 *     The document title parts.
 *
 *     @type string $title   Title of the viewed page.
 *     @type string $page    Optional. Page number if paginated.
 *     @type string $tagline Optional. Site description when on home page.
 *     @type string $site    Optional. Site title when not on home page.
 * }
 */
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function ( $title ) {

    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() )
        unset($title['tagline']);

    return $title;

}, 10, 1 );
```

---

Looking back on this; the [`pre_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/) filter is pretty interesting. Essentially before it processes the title it'll run this filter. If the result isn't empty (which was not expected) then the process is short-circuited.

```
$title = apply_filters( 'pre_get_document_title', '' );
if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
    return $title;
}
```

That means that if you defined the title, it doesn't have to worry about anything else. The nice thing is that you can make exceptions to the rule. So to answer your original question:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', function( $title ) {

    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {

        // Return blog title on front page

        $title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    }

    return $title;

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line:

```
$title = "$title";
```

You actually just change the `$title` to itself. If you change it to

```
$title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
```

the returned title on the front page is going to be the name of your blog. You can put any string there. Also, it is not necessary to call the globals here.

Here is some code that should work:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', function ( $title, $sep ) {

    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() )
        $title = "Any string you want to have";

    return $title;

}, 10, 2 );
```